# Application Load Balancers Requests Hanging

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

In my aws env requests are hanging at the ALB for some reason. I haven't been able to identify a cause yet aside from Cache hanging requests there and possibly the session write being left open causing it to wait. what might be the possible reason for of it ,Are there other diagnostic tools for recommendation to add into the stack to try to debug this issue?

Comment: Hello novonimo, we only face the issue of packet drops and REJECT requests at this time in our one of the ALB , can you pl explain a bit what might be the possible issues with it ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.